# How does Sample Angular-App know how to get the "projects"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependencies

I'm looking at the popular [Sample Angular App](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) by Pawel Kozlowski and Peter Bacon Darwin.

I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding how, in the file [`projects.html`](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/projects/projects-list.tpl.html#L11), the line

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
```

manages to get the `projects`.

I'm trying to trace the pipeline but I am hitting a dead end.

I can see that the whole `projects.html` is being placed by the router into the `index.html` file. The controller of that area is called [`AppCtrl`](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/index.html#L12). However, looking into this controller, there is no sign of anything remotely related to getting the `projects` from the server and storing them in the scope.

I'm completely baffled as to how these projects make it to my screen.

Can someone please explain? I'm going out of my mind :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing and controller for projects.html page are defined here:

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/projects/projects.js

'resolve' does get to API to load projects:

```
resolve:{
      projects:['Projects', function (Projects) {
        //TODO: fetch only for the current user
        return Projects.all();
      }],
      authenticatedUser: securityAuthorizationProvider.requireAuthenticatedUser
    }
```

Then `projects` dependency injected into controller and used here:

```
$scope.projects = projects;
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where does `Projects` come from? And what is `projects`? As far as I can see, it's the name of this module. You inject a module into it's own `config`?

Comment: 'Projects' is a service described here: https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/resources/projects.js it's injected into resolver 'projects'. (details about resolve here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider )

Comment: I don't see where it is injected. I only see these injected `'resources.projects', 'productbacklog', 'sprints', 'security.authorization'`

Comment: When you use `resolve`, you create a module, so it looks like: `resolve: {var1 : module1, var2: module2, etc}`, see 'The array notation' here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Comment: But how does `resolve` know what `Projects` means? The first time it's mentioned is in the `resolve` function and never before. So how does `resolve` know what it is?

Comment: I'm not sure in details, but angular works in this order: firstly all module declarations fired, then `.config` calls, then `.run` calls. And `resolve` fired right before controller runned, which is  added by ngRoute to specific view(specified in `.config`). So when `resolve` called, `$injector` already knows what `Project` means, because it's a part of a module  `'resources.projects'`

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/projects/projects.js

```
.config(['$routeProvider', 'securityAuthorizationProvider', function ($routeProvider, securityAuthorizationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/projects', {
    templateUrl:'projects/projects-list.tpl.html',
    controller:'ProjectsViewCtrl',
    resolve:{
      projects:['Projects', function (Projects) {
        //TODO: fetch only for the current user
        return Projects.all();
      }],
      authenticatedUser: securityAuthorizationProvider.requireAuthenticatedUser
    }
  });
}])
```

As you can see the `ProjectsViewCtrl` is being passed to that view, and the projects variable is being taken from there.

Comment: But where does `Projects` (with a capital `P`) come from?